# How to pass value back from WinJS.UI.Pages.render

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I am using the WinJS.UI.Pages.render call to load fragments into a page. I [read that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770590.aspx) a page's ready method can return a promise that completes when the page is ready. I thought that this promise is what would be returned by the WinJS.UI.Pages.render method, but it is not. I was thinking this would be a nice mechanism to asynchronously pass values back from the fragment to the caller.

Is it possible to access the ready promise from the WinJS.UI.Pages.render promise done handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code in the implementation, it *looks* like this may actually be a *bug* in WinJS. The `WinJS.UI.Pages.render` method **does** return a promise, but it's the one from just after `processed` is complete and and results in the *control instance* been returned as the completed promises value.

Your best bet is to place an additional promise as a member of your Page class. Then when you get `render`, peel off from that promise, rather than the `render` promise itself.

It's important that you use the promise created in the constructor or similar, since the promise returned from `render` is going to complete when `processed` is called on your page class -- **before** your `ready` returns, so accessing the value immediately after the `render` completes, your `ready` method has *not* yet been called.

Comment: It's actually a deliberate design choice, not a bug. I don't think it was the right choice, but it is what it is.

Comment: Le sad -- looking at the way the code is written it doesn't feel quite intentional; looks like theres a missing assignment :) Thanks for the insight Chris :)